# Not able to Clear values in EditBox of type numeric Passcode

Tags: android

```
passCode1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passCode1);
```

> this edit text box is of type numeric password i am not able to clear the value and it has numeric restriction to enter only numbers from 0 - 9

Comment: do you want to clear password from edittext?

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: try passCode1.setText(null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**numberPassword, textPassword, phone, date, text, ..** whatever it is, you can clear the field by calling `passCode1.setText(null);`

Comment: i tried this earlier but didnt work i am having this error message when i debug '// Compiled from Integer.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
// Signature: Ljava/lang/Number;Ljava/lang/Comparable<Ljava/lang/Integer;>;
public final class java.lang.Integer extends java.lang.Number implements java.lang.Comparable {
  
  // Field descriptor #11 I
  public static final int MAX_VALUE = 2147483647;
  
  // Field descriptor #11 I
  public static final int MIN_VALUE = -2147483648;
  
  // Field descriptor #11 I
  public static final int SIZE = 32;'

Comment: I didn't get it. Edit your question and add the error there. Also include some more code (where declaration, initialization and .setText() are called).